# Creating element in place

Tags: javascript

I want to create an element in place where javascript function run.

```
<script>
var uniqid='an unique Id';
document.write('<iframe id='+uniqid+'></iframe>');
someAsyncFunction(callback)
</script>
```

in other part of code I set additional parameters for this element

```
<script>
callback=function(paramfromcallback){
    getElementById(uniqid).url=paramfromcallback;
}
</script>
```

but this is not work in IE. I can't find this element.

My problem is:

1. There are many elements on page, for each element must be set only this element parameters
2. I do not  know which element is parent, I do not know the script element ID. I need insert an element in place where are first script called
3. First part of code executed before any call back, and I want to keep it asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the order your script blocks are hit, you could have a number of issues here.  `document.write()` creates interesting problems with inline script.  More often than not, any script that comes after it won't be able to use the results of the doc.write until after the page finishes loading -- or from within another `document.write()` block.  Waiting for the window to be fully loaded could solve your issue.  How about something like this -

Defined Once:

```
function callback(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el !== null) {
    el.url = 'http://google.com';
  }
}
```

Then anywhere you want to write out an iframe:

```
(function(){
  var id = 'an_unique_Id';
  document.write('<iframe id='+id+'></iframe>');

  var l = window.onload;
  var n = function() { someAsyncFunction(function() { callback(id); }); };

   window.onload = (typeof l == 'function') ? function() { l(); n(); } : n;
})();
```

Comment: waiting for the document load help me

Answer (score 0):

First, use:

```
document.getElementById(uniqid).url = 'http://google.com';
```

The method is part of the document object, so you can only use it by prepending `document`.

Second, use:

```
var callback = function() {
```

Will not break your code probably, but variables should be declared with `var`

Comment: I don't know what value I must set to url attribute before callback finished. I do edit mypost

Comment: You still need to use `document.` for getElementId before it works. So: `document.getElementById()`